# Sorting nested NSArrays with Objects

Tags: sorting, properties, nested, nsarray, alphabetical

Hello you smart people out there. I need your help (again).

I have an NSArray that contains  arrays of objects. Among the object's properties, one is called "name".

Each of the nested Arrays contains objects with the same 'name' (but different values for other properties). Simplified, it looks like this:

```
@[
  @[myObject.name=@"c",myObject.name=@"c",myObject.name=@"c"],
  @[myObject.name=@"a",myObject.name=@"a"],
  @[myObject.name=@"b",myObject.name=@"b",myObject.name=@"b",myObject.name=@"b",myObject.name=@"b"]
]
```

Now, I want to sort my array, in such a way, that the nested arrays are in alphabetical order, like this:

```
@[
  @[myObject.name=@"a",myObject.name=@"a"],
  @[myObject.name=@"b",myObject.name=@"b",myObject.name=@"b",myObject.name=@"b",myObject.name=@"b"],
  @[myObject.name=@"c",myObject.name=@"c",myObject.name=@"c"]
]
```

Does any of you have a hint on how to approach this? The nested arrays should not be sorted or rearranged internally.

Thanks for your advice

Comment: In the mean time, I have solved this by putting a sort method earlier in the creation of my Arrays. I'll leave my question out of curiosity, and perhaps for others that run into this

Comment: `array = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSArray * _Nonnull obj1, NSArray * _Nonnull obj2) { MyObjectClass *el1 = [obj1 firstObject]; MyObjectClass *el2 = [obj2 firstObject]; return [el1.name compare:el2.name];}];` should do the trick.